# ALB: Should load-balance health-checks retry on failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, healthcheck, amazon-alb

We have some AWS ECS-based Fargate-hosted tasks/services running behind many ALBs. We seem to frequently get not-meaningful alerts from our own monitoring in our health-checks. It happens every twenty or thirty minutes, even when all systems are working and no users are complaining of issues. The healthchecks are very light. The interior services just do simple DB pings. The exterior services just do API pings that do simple DB pings.

Given that transient infrastructure issues are a fact of life and such frequent requests are likely to experience them whenever AWS experiences fractional instabilities, should we be retrying a few times before simply allowing those API handlers to fail, and to make sure the healthcheck timeouts also allow for whatever that maximum period is going to be? Should we just, maybe, not necessarily send warnings about every failure?